# Gulp.js GUI with Electron

Tags: javascript, github, gulp, electron

I have been planning to start working on a new application for my current college project. What I would like to do is create an electron app that will start specific tasks based on a gulpfile.js.

This is mostly to let people start the gulp tasks even if they aren't used to work with the terminal .

Now the question is: If I package the application (macOS) and the final user don't have any node/gulp.js installed globally, will this work? Is it possible to package an electron app with gulp and fire some gulp taks anyway?

I don't have enough time to start the project without knowing if it will work, that's why I'm addressing this to you guys, I need your help in the subject :)

I have also searched on Google for some solutions, but I didn't find any.

Thank you!

Comment: I have to say that I'm not expecting you to give me any code, just to let me know if you think this is feasible or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about gulp in particular, but as it seems to be an npm module, you'll be able to install it locally with your electron app. In the terminal `cd` to your `electron/resources/app` folder and run

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp -D
```

(as shown on https://gulpjs.com/)

You then should see a `node_modules` folder in the same directory, which contains the install of gulp. This can then be packaged in the same way as any other electron app.